Rayleigh quotient for non-Hermitian matrices

I have been learning matrix theory from 'Matrix Analysis' by Horn and Johnson and learnt the Rayleigh-Ritz Theorem for Hermitian matrices. However, I cannot prove this relation when the matrix A is not necessarily Hermitian.
Some insight would be much appreciated.

Hint: if $x$ is an eigenvector for eigenvalue $\lambda$, then what is $x^* A x$?

If x is an Eigenvector, then x * Ax = x * (Eval * x) = (Eval) (x * x).
But isn't that a special case? How to know max and min conditions?

Any special case of $\left|\frac{x^* A x}{x^* x}\right|$ is $\ge$ the minimum and $\le$ the maximum of these.
